# ROS installation troubles

Tags: ros, installation, sudo, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am following the ROS installation guide for noetic on an ubuntu focal 20.04 machine. This is the second time I have done this, and before the keys were there, but now it only shows the key for the curl command and it cuts off the rest of the command for using the sudo command, which was there last time I installed it. What is the rest of that command, as the curl command is not working for me. [This](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2FUbuntu.2FSources.Set_up_your_keys) is the link to the instructions, specifically I am looking at the code box in section 1.3 that says `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -` And the rest appears to be missing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381515/ros-installation-troubles/) by [zippyzoo77](https://answers.ros.org/users/73815/zippyzoo77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-01**:\

> And the rest appears to be missing.

What "rest" do you expect?

> the curl command is not working for me.

Please elaborate.

The command is correct and working just fine. There is nothing missing. `curl` prints whatever it gets to the terminal by default, and `apt-key add -` means: read stdout and add that as a key. Check the manpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so I was missing that it was all one command, and the curl command was not installed yet on my machine because it is brand new. My brain saw the line and thought two commands, my brain was incorrect on that.

---

Originally posted by [zippyzoo77](https://answers.ros.org/users/73815/zippyzoo77/) with karma: 13 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-02**:
yes exactly, one single command. You can also download the certificate using curl into a file and then read this. But that isn't required, thus the above command.

Yeah, curl doesn't get installed with ubuntu 20.04 per default. I've stumbled upon that as well. So working now? If yes, please mark the question as solved.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-02**:
If `curl` is not present by default, *that* (ie: the fact it needs to be separately installed first) would be something to add to the instructions.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-02**:
agreed and done.